# Should I use escape strings in sequelize (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a function that fetches products with offset and limit.

```
 function f(offset,limit, callback) {  
    models.Product.findAll({
    offset: offset,limit: limit
    }).then(function (products) {
    ...
    }).catch(function (error) {
            callback(error, null);
    });
    }
```

Server gets offset and limit via POST query from client. 
Should I check limit and offset values myself or sequelize will do it instead of me? Will it catch all errors in 'catch' method?

For example, server expected values - offset:0, limit: 100, 
but got - offset: -87, limit: 'rchk' or some kind of sql injection.

Should I pass this data to findAll or check input data myself before passing?

Comment: I don't know enough about sequelize to answer all of these questions, but as to the question of whether you should be escaping inputs to your query, the answer is always yes.  Even if it originates from within your own server-side code.

Comment: @JohnHalbert sequelize abstracts the querying similar to how you would query in mongodb. So the OP needs to check if the sequelize library already escapes the values passed to `findAll` by default (but I'm pretty sure it does) as long as raw queries are not used. But even then it is the same with any other SQL library, where you should always use bind parameters and query placeholders to pass data to the query so that the library does the correct escaping internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize will escape (to prevent injection attacks) the limit and offset values for you. It won't, however, validate it for you, so if you don't want a `SequelizeDatabaseError` thrown when some fool passes `'limit: monkeys'` then you need to screen that yourself.

If you were running raw queries (with `Sequelize#query` then you'd want to use placeholders as t.niese suggests)